# How do you make an accurate, integrable approximation of $a \operatorname{mod} \left(\frac xb,1 \right)$ with a scaling constant $N$?

Tags: approximation-theory

I'm working on a project where I'm working with modulo functions. However, to continue, I need to integrate integral powers of a weighted sum of them (e.g of the form $\left(c+\operatorname{weighted sum} \right)^p$, with $c$ a real, positive constant, and $p \in \mathbb{Z}$). So, I first tried Fourier series. However, since the weights are pretty high, the errors blew up, and the amount of terms necessary to correct them are prohibitively high. So, I need another way to create the modulo functions.

This leads me to my question: just like the title says, is there some approximation of  $a \operatorname{mod} \left(\frac xb,1 \right)$, $f(x)$ (with $a,b, \geq 1, \in \mathbb{R}$), that has an elementary, closed form antiderivative, has a scaling constant $N$ so that as $N \to \infty$, $|a \operatorname{mod} \left(\frac xb,1 \right)-f(x)| \to 0$ (hopefully $\sim \mathcal{O} \left(10^{-\operatorname{|poly(N)|}}\right)$, but not neccessary) at least on $\{ bk+0.1 \leq x \leq bk+0.9, k=\{0,1,2,3..,\lceil \frac nb \rceil\}\}$, with $n \in \mathbb{R}$ (but hopefully over all $x \in [0,n]$), and has a constant number of terms $k$ that independent of $N,n,a,b$.

Comment: Did you try to use the substitution $x=1/y$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე How would that help me?

Comment: There's something I don't understand here - $a\ \mbox{mod} (\frac{x}{b} )$ itself is elementary and has a closed form antiderivative, so why approximate it? Restricted to intervals between jumps, it's linear, and a square of a weighted sum thereof consists of pieces of parabolas.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt While that is true, the *square* (and other integral powers) of the function does not have such a closed form antiderivative (however, if they do, I would like to know).

Comment: Isn't the modulo function linear in each interval between jumps? Isn't the square of a linear function a parabola?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt Yes, but it isn't parabolic over $[0,b]$-- there are cuts, made more complicated by multiplying another mod function to it.

Comment: Sure, but it's a purely algebraic problem - you catalog where the jumps are, assemble the parabolas in between, and integrate them on each interval.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt Is there a way to determine where the jumps are, and the period for a product of $p$ mod functions? Or should that be another question?

Comment: I don't think it's a good strategy to multiply out the $p$ factors. Just construct the weighted sum on each interval between jumps, which gives a linear function, and then take the $p$-th power of that. Of course you know where the jumps are, they occur spaced by $b_i $ for the $i$-th term in your weighted sum, just put them all in a big list. Your function is not periodic if the $b_i $ are not commensurate.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt I wouldn't consider that efficient, as there are, at most $\prod_{i=1} b_i$ jumps, and cataloguing all of them would take a while, and probably require manual analysis. Hence, the original request for approximations.

Comment: I don't understand your reluctance. The jumps are at $b_1, 2b_1, 3b_1 ,\ldots,b_2, 2b_2, 3b_2,\ldots, b_3,\ldots $. This is trivial to program and to sort. With any approximation, you'll invest orders of magnitude more effort per jump to achieve convergence, and your integrations also won't be simpler.

Comment: Oh sorry, by some reason I imagined it was $a\operatorname{mod}(1,x/b)$ :)

Comment: Then, as @MichaelEngelhardt explains, it is just plain integrable, with the antiderivative$$\frac{ab}2\left(\left\lfloor\frac xb\right\rfloor+\operatorname{mod}\left(\frac xb,1\right)^2\right)$$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Ok, for example, what's the process to integrating this: $$\left(4\operatorname{mod}\left(\frac x5,1\right)+10\operatorname{mod}\left(\frac x{33},1\right)\right )^p$$ (say $p=2$ for now).

Comment: Sorry again, seems I suffer from attention deficit - did not notice you need powers of these things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the concrete example given by the OP in comments,
$$
f(x) = \left( 4\ \mbox{mod} \left( \frac{x}{5} ,1\right) + 10\ \mbox{mod} \left( \frac{x}{33} ,1\right) \right)^{p} \ .
$$
$f(x)$ is periodic with period $5\cdot 33 = 165$. It is discontinuous at the points $\{ 5n : n\in \mathbb{Z} \} \cup \{ 33n : n\in \mathbb{Z} \} $; these can be easily listed and sorted in ascending order within any integration range one may be interested in (and for a periodic example such as this, it's of course sufficient to be able to treat one period). The entire integral of $f$ can be assembled by summing up the integrals over individual intervals between consecutive discontinuities, for all such intervals contained in the integration range one is interested in.

Consider an arbitrary such interval, $[d_i ,d_{i+1} ]$, where the $d_i $ denote the discontinuities. On this interval (caveat - for negative $x$, one might have to specify exactly how one interprets the mod function),
$$
f(x) = \left( 4\ \mbox{mod} \left( \frac{d_i }{5} ,1\right) + 10\ \mbox{mod} \left( \frac{d_i}{33} ,1\right) + \left( \frac{4}{5} + \frac{10}{33} \right) (x-d_i ) \right)^{p} \ .
$$
or, to streamline the notation,
$$
f(x) = (s+tx)^p
$$
and one has the integral
$$
\int_{d_i}^{d_{i+1} } dx\, f(x) = \frac{(s+td_{i+1} )^{p+1} }{t(p+1)} - \frac{(s+td_i )^{p+1} }{t(p+1)}
$$
It remains to sum up these contributions; note that the first and the last interval may be only partially integrated over and then the lower or upper integration limits, respectively, have to be appropriately adjusted.

Comment: While not *exactly* answering the question, it is the best (and only) answer given (at least so far), so as is my nature, I'll wait a day before accepting to allow for any new answers. But in the meantime, here's a +1 from me. Thanks!

Comment: Since no one else responded, accepted!

Comment: @DUO - I hope it helps in practice - this should be straightforward to implement computationally.